# How to select both the values from two Select queries using Joins and do a difference between them in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, join, subquery

This is the first query from which I have to select the value of AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_AFTER_1980

```
 SELECT
     AVG(AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE) AS AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_AFTER_1980
FROM Movie M 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT avg(R.stars) AS AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE, R.mID MOVIEID
    FROM Rating R
    GROUP BY R.mID
) INTER1
    ON INTER1.MOVIEID = M.mID AND M.year >= 1980
```

This is the second query from which I have to select the value of AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_BEFORE_1980

```
SELECT
    AVG(AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE) AS AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_BEFORE_1980
FROM Movie M 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AVG(R.stars) AS AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE, R.mID MOVIEID
    FROM Rating R
    GROUP BY R.mID
) INTER2
    ON INTER2.MOVIEID = M.mID AND M.year <= 1980
```

After selecting both these average values from these two select queries I need to do the difference between the two. I'm trying to do this  in SQLite. In other words what I have to do is:

```
(AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_AFTER_1980 - AVERAGE_OF_MOVIES_BEFORE_1980).
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can logically combine the two queries by using conditional aggregation to compute the average over each respective timeframe.

```
SELECT
     AVG(CASE WHEN M.year > 1980 THEN AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE END) -
     AVG(CASE WHEN M.year < 1980 THEN AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE END) AS DIFF_AVG_AFTER_BEFORE_1980
FROM Movie M 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT R.mID AS MOVIEID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVERAGEOFEACHMOVIE
    FROM Rating R
    GROUP BY R.mID
) INTER1
    ON INTER1.MOVIEID = M.mID
```

The reason this trick should work is that SQLite's `AVG()` function ignores `NULL` values.  Hence, for each conditional average, the data points which fall out of the time range would return `NULL` and would therefore be completely ignored in the average.

As a note, you might want to use `M.year >= 1980` or maybe `M.year <= 1980`, because right now you are completely excluding the year 1980 from your calculation.  Presumably, the data from this year belongs somewhere in your report.

Comment: Added more clarity to my question

Comment: @dsfasdfadf My answer doesn't change much, and you could have just used my previous answer.  Just take the difference between the conditional `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to achieve this with out using CASE just by using Joins. I don't want you to write the complete query just  pointers in the direction that I should take.

Comment: I can't think of another way to do this other than what I wrote above, except to just subtract two independent subqueries.  The issue is that you want to use different ranges in the same query.  Well, the `WHERE` clause can only use one range, not two, hence the need for some IF (e.g. `CASE`) functionality in the query.  Is there some reason you can't use a `CASE` expression?

Comment: Someone else may give you a better answer...you can hold off on upvoting etc. until others have had a chance.

Comment: I want to accomplish this task using full outer join but full outer joins are not supported in MySQL. This is a exercise problem where I'm trying to make the code work with both MySQL and SQLite. Your code works but I'm trying to make it work with joins to strengthen my basics. That was the reason I asked you for suggestion. Anyways Thank you for your great help.

Comment: @dsfasdfadf Full outer joins _are_ possible in MySQL, through a workaround.  Post your query and a MySQL version can be given.